# Can i open a website through an Amazon Web Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to open a website,like facebook.com for example, on an amazon web service?

My objective is to automate a certain task in a game and to do so without having to be online on my computer. The point is to spend less time on that game, but to not be left behind on the progress. (I'm building a bot to automate the daily tasks there, just need to know if i can now leave everything running on amazon)

Another project i want to do is to automate access to my email account and perform certain tasks depending on the emails i receive.

You get the point, i tried searching on google but i only find results about creating or hosting your own website in there and not about accessing existing websites and using automation in them.

Comment: Yes you can access other external APIs. If you are running your bot in an EC2 instance, open ports 80 (if needed) and 443 to the internet (0.0.0.0/0) in your egress rules.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a virtual private server - basically a computer in the cloud that you control and is always on.

AWS have a service called [LightSail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/) for this kind of purpose. Under the hood lightsail just uses EC2, but lightsail takes away a lot of the options and configuration to provide a simpler 'click and go' kind of service.

Once you have a server you can schedule regular tasks. Depending on the complexity of your needs, you could look at using [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) as a scheduler and [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) for you http requests.

For the specifics of any project you have I would suggest opening a new question with details of what you are trying to do, the reading you have done, and examples of any code you have tried.

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out and come back in a few days with what i was able to do and if needed I'll open a new question with a better structure as you suggested